# How to transform map into another?

Tags: scala

What would be the most efficient(elegant) way to transform the following Map

```
Map("aaa" -> Seq(1, 2, 3), "bbb" -> Seq(1, 2), "ccc" -> Seq(1, 3))
```

into

```
Map(1 -> Seq("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 2 -> Seq("aaa", "bbb"), 3 -> Seq("aaa", "ccc"))
```

?

Comment: `input.view.flatMap { case (k, vs) => vs.map(_ -> k) }.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).toMap` in 2.13 but that's totally lazy to avoid spending 1 minute to write an one-liner...

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok That is not going to give the right answer because that `flatMap` is on a `Map` so duplicates will be removed.

Comment: They wont, I tested it in ammonite before commenting. After `flatMap` you'll have `View` which is lazy `Seq`, so the pairs will be preserved. (`Map("aaa" -> Seq(1, 2, 3), "bbb" -> Seq(1, 2), "ccc" -> Seq(1, 3)).view.flatMap { case (k, vs) => vs.map(_ -> k) }.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).toMap` returns `res13: Map[Int, collection.View[String]] = Map(1 -> View("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 2 -> View("aaa", "bbb"), 3 -> View("aaa", "ccc"))`). The only issse would be that I would have `View` instead of `Seq` as values, so that is something to address with `.mapValues(_.toSeq)`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Apologies, I had not realised that `view` would change the type in that way. I assumed that adding `view` was purely a performance issue, but in this case it changes the meaning as well. I'm not sure I like that behaviour, but at least I know it is there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Scala 2.13:

```
Map("aaa" -> Seq(1, 2, 3), "bbb" -> Seq(1, 2), "ccc" -> Seq(1, 3))
  .toList
  .flatMap{ case (k,v) => v.map(_ -> k) }
  .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

For earlier versions you will need to replace `groupMap` with `group` followed by `map`